# Black screen after monitor resolution change Lubuntu 18

Tags: lubuntu, display, display-resolution, monitor, lxrandr

Trying different monitors on my freshly installed Lubuntu 18.1 (not by myself only..) it recognized both, but had a stretched picture on the big TV monitor; went to the menu for resolution, it told me a warning when I tried to apply a different resolution, I did not understand.

I saved new resolution and did a restart, ending with a black screen after decrypt and log in. Some other articles tell me here to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get a console, but what commands I need to return to normal display since I am a console newbie?

The only thing so far I could find it has to do with xrandr...It is an AMD 64 processor, but graphics card integrated I could not find a proper description in the system info. Unfortunately, I do not remember on which resolution it was, but I think it was 1280x800.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file:

~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop

reboot.

Now retry other resolutions, only press SAVE if the new resolution tests ok (the 15 seconds warning, etc)

If by accident you lose your desktop just remove lxrandr-autostart.desktop and reboot again.